# Feedback code review dealing Inheritance and Polymorphism for Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am working on a programming project dealing with Inheritance and Polymorphism. I just need that, someone can provide me a feedback of my work, in the meantime I want to thank you for your time in providing your feedback. The textbook question follows:

Design a class named `Triangle` that extends to `GeometricObject`. The class contains:

- Three double data fields named side1, side2 and side3 with default values 1.0 to denote three sides.
- A no-arg constructor that creates a default triangle.
- A constructor that creates a triangle with the specified side1, side2 and side3.
- The accessor methods for all three data fields.
- A method named `getArea()` that returns the area of this triangle.
- A method named `getPerimeter()` that returns the perimeter of this triangle.
- a method named `toString()` that returns a string description for the triangle.

The toString() method is implemented as follows: 
return `Triangle: side1 = " + side1 + " side2= " side2 + "side3" + side3;`

Without taking in consideration for the GeometricObeject class, I only done the Triangle class and the test program so here is my code:

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
private double side1, side2, side3; private double base, height;
public Triangle() { 
side1 = 1.0;
side2 = 1.0; 
side3 = 1.0;
}
public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, double base, double height) {
this.side1 = side1; 
this.side2 = side2; 
this.side3 = side3; 
this.base = base; 
this.height = height;
}
public double getSide1() { 
return side1;
}
public double getSide2() { 
return side2;
}
public double getSide3() { 
return side3;
}
public double getBase() { 
return base;
}
public double getHeight() { 
return height;
}
public void setBase(double newBase) { 
base = newBase;
}
public void setHeight(double newHeight) {
height = newHeight; }
public void setSide1(double newSide1) { 
side1= newSide1;
}
public void setSide2(double newSide2) { 
side2= newSide2;
}
public void setSide3(double newSide3) { 
side3= newSide3;
}
public String toString() {
return (“Triangle : side1 " + getSide1() + "triangle side 2 " + getSide2()
+ "get side 3" + getSide3()) ;
}
public String toString() {
return (“Get base" + getBase() + "get height" + getHeight());
}
public void display() {
}
public double area() {
return 0.5 * base * height;
}
public double perimeter() { 
return side1 + side2 + side3;
} }


Test file
public class TestTriangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
triangle t = new Triangle();
System.out.println("A triangle " + t.toString()); 
System.out.println("The radius is " + t.getRadius()); 
System.out.println("The area is " + t.getArea())
} }
```

Comment: Welcome, This isn't really an appropriate question for this forum - you need a clear and specific question that has an answer.

Comment: What is your exact question, can you specify what you exactly want to ask?

Comment: Do you want feedback on code that is working, or do you want help to fix your code? If the first case is true, then you should consider posting to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I just need a code review. Sorry about my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of Inheritance and Polymorphism as you to take in your example is not up to the mark, why? Because,

1. Inheritance shows "Is a" Relationship, and if it is then you don't need to write that much code in your child class. We only have to put general code in the base class and just use that in the child class.
2. Polymorphism - As per my reading you didn't use polymorphism in it.